# Can I Send Emails On Behalf Of My Clients?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sendmail

i am developing an application in which i have to send emails on behalf of my clients

can we use any service like aws ses or vero

if we use php mail function it will send mail in spam due to change in from emails

after a lots of research i got to know about aws ses reply to option .

any other better approach for this ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many 3rd party options such as https://mandrillapp.com that allow you to send emails via their API.

Comment: tnx for your help 

 will mandrillapp allow us to send emails on behalf of any other mail which is not validated 

will these mails reach inbox or they will the go to spam ?

Comment: Yes it will allow you to send emails on behalf of any other email. Mandrill helps you track so called "spam rate" - how many receivers marked your emails as spam. But bottom line is that no - they will not go to spam.